# Angular.js: testing click on directive

Tags: jquery, angularjs, unit-testing, angularjs-directive

I have an Angular.js directive which I am trying to write a test for. Basically, it is a wrapper for a checkbox, such as that when the wrapper is clicked, the checkbox's state is changed. The problem is that I don't know how to replicate this behaviour inside a unit test. What I have for a test is this:

```
describe('Checkbox field', function() {
var elm, scope;

    beforeEach(module('MyApp'));
    beforeEach(module('app/partials/checkboxfield.html'));

    beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $compile) {
        elm = angular.element(
          '<checkboxfield data="data" model="value"></checkboxfield>');
        scope = $rootScope;
        scope.value = false;
        $compile(elm)(scope);
        scope.$digest();
    }));

    it('should change checkbox value on wrapper click', inject(function($compile, $rootScope) {
        var wrapper = elm.find('div').eq(0);
        //var wrapper = $('div.checkbox');
        wrapper.click();
        expect(checkbox.prop('checked')).toBe(true);
        expect(scope.value).toBe(true);
        wrapper.click();
        expect(checkbox.prop('checked')).toBe(false);
        expect(scope.value).toBe(false);
    }));
});
```

Angular.js comes with jqLite, so when I run "elm.find('div').eq(0)", I don't get the click() method. I would simply use jQuery instead but every time I use one of its selectors, no items are returned; I always get $(whatever).length === 0.

Just to clarify, I am using [karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor) as seen [here](http://newtriks.com/2013/04/26/how-to-test-an-angularjs-directive/).

Comment: `beforeEach(module('app/partials/checkboxfield.html'));` is completely irrelevant. Moreover, `$compile` takes template string and returns the element. Your usage seems wrong.

Comment: Hi! I am using http://newtriks.com/2013/04/26/how-to-test-an-angularjs-directive/ as an example so I've pretty much copied the structure from there. Besides, when I remove the `beforeEach(module('app/partials/checkboxfield.html'));` line, Karma starts complaining about unexpected GET petitions.

Comment: I see. That example is using html2js karma plugin: https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor retry after installing it.

Comment: I have installed it already. In fact, I have run other tests inside the same suite and they worked flawlessly - I just omitted them for the same of brevity. It is only this one I am having issues with.

Answer (score 0):

You should test the value of your scope variable instead of the element attribute value. Because if everything went well then the value of the scope variable should have changed.

For example, the following test passes:

```
describe('Checkbox field', function () {
    var $scope, elm;

    beforeEach(module('myApp'))

    beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $compile) {
      $scope = $rootScope.$new();
      $scope.value = true;
      $scope.data = "Click on me";

      elm = $compile('<checkboxfield data="data" model="value"></checkboxfield>')($scope);
    }))

    it('should change checkbox value on wrapper click', function () {
        expect($scope.value).toBe(true);
        elm.click();
        expect($scope.value).toBe(false);
        elm.click();
        expect($scope.value).toBe(true);
    })
  })
```

Comment: The problem is that the click() method is not defined. When I try to call it, I get the usual "undefined is not a function" complaint.

Comment: Please note my usage of `$compile` is different than yours. I am also not using html2js plugin. `elm` and also `elm.click` are defined.

Comment: I have just ran your code as is and I'm getting the exact same error. :( Which version of Angular are you using? I'm using 1.3.0-beta.8 - perhaps this could be causing the error?

Also, I'm using jQuery 1.8.2. I'm not sure about whether this could be related.